# Use CSS3 animations with a list in Angular

Tags: angularjs, css, animation

I have a list of items with a checkbox for each item. I'm using CSS3 animations (this particular CSS http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and Angular to manipulate this list. I've managed to animate adding a new element to the list, but I'm having trouble animating removal of an item from the list (e.g. deleting or checking the checkbox).

This is what a list item looks like:

```
<li ng-class="{'animated fadeInDown' : task.isNew, 'animated fadeOutRight' : delete}" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{is_done: false}" ng-mouseover="hovering = true" ng-mouseout="hovering = false">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.is_done" ng-click="toggleDone(task)">
    <span class="done-{{task.is_done}}" ng-hide="editing" ng-dblclick="editing = true">{{task.name}} </span><a href ng-show="hovering" ng-click="deleteTask(task); delete = true">x</a>
</li>
```

When I add a new task, the property task.isNew is set to true which sets 'animated fadeInDown' class to the list element. However, when I click on delete link, I would expect the class to be 'animated fadeOutRight' and that the removal is actually animated. This doesn't happen though, the item is removed but no animation is displayed.

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you replicate it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lHTCXh5GDnjiJ83DG2OA?p=preview

Comment: That works because you're not actually removing an item from the list in Angular. My example doesn't work because the deleteTask(task) function removes the item from scope before it has a chance to get animated off the list.